# sql query to break down count of every combination

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I need a Postgresql Query that returns the count of every type of combination of record.

For example, I have a table T with columns A, B, C, D, E and other columns that are not of importance:

```
Table T
--------------
A | B | C | D | E
```

The query should return a table R with the values from columns A, B, C, D, and a count for how many times each configuration occurs with the specified E value.

```
Table R
---------------
A | B | C | D | count
```

When all of the counts for each record are added together, it should equal the total number of records in the original table.

It seems like a very simple problem, but due to my lack of SQL knowledge, I cannot figure out how to do this.

The only solution I can think of is this:

```
select a, b, c, d, count(*)
  from T
  where e = 'abc'
  group by a, b, c, d
```

But when adding the counts up from this query, it is way more than the count of the original table.  It seems like count(*) shouldn't be used, or i'm just totally going about this the wrong way.  I'd really appreciate any advice as to how I should go about this.  Thank you all.

Comment: Maybe you are fooled by NULLs? please show us some data.

Comment: I agree with @wildplasser - what you're showing us should work fine. So the problem lies somewhere in what you're *not* showing us yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was something really stupid. I forgot to specify the where 'E' = 'ABC' clause in the select count(*) when comparing the count. Thanks anyway for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` values couldn't possibly fool you. Consider this demo:

```
WITH t(a,b,c,d) AS (
    VALUES
     (1,2,3,4)
    ,(1,2,3,NULL)
    ,(2,2,3,NULL)
    ,(2,2,3,NULL)
    ,(2,2,3,4)
    ,(2,NULL,NULL,NULL)
    ,(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
    )
SELECT a, b, c, d, count(*)
FROM   t
GROUP  BY a, b, c, d
ORDER  BY a, b, c, d;

 a | b | c | d | count
---+---+---+---+-------
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |     1
 1 | 2 | 3 |   |     1
 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |     1
 2 | 2 | 3 |   |     2
 2 |   |   |   |     1
   |   |   |   |     1
```

There must be some other misunderstanding here.